# I want to run report(.html file) of protractor-html-reportor

Tags: protractor, angular

I am doing end-2-end testing with protractor.

And for creating a report of all these test cases, I am using `protractor-html-reporter`, which creates an `.html` file as report of all these test cases. All is good with that part.

What I want that after creating that html file, at the end I want to run it automatically on browser. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Are you using any javascript task managers like `grunt` or `gulp`?

Comment: [alecxe](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/5574/alecxe) I am using grunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `grunt` - there is a related grunt plugin - [`grunt-open`](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-open). You can configure this plugin to open your generated report once the tests are done.